# Xcode files Localization - Not able to add more than English

Tags: xcode, localization

In the localizable.strings, I'm not able no add more languages than English. The `"+"` doesn't appear. On the right panel of the localizable, the location is `"en.lproj/Localizable.strings"`

Any ideas? May be there something to do with the -`Info.plist`?

In this file, the only line related is `"Localization native development | String | en"`

Comment: What XCode version are you using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using XCode 4.4 or 4.4.1, please consider this area in the Files Inspector:

[image]

You will get this:

[image]

Then, you can add localized copy:

[image]

Of course, you have first to go into Project Settings > Info > Localization and click on the "+" in the bottom-left corner to add languages.

[image]

Then you can localize your files.

Answer (score 1):

I meet this problem too when upgrade from XCode 4.0 to XCode 4.4.1. If I create a new project on XCode 4.4.1, the localization works fine and the first letter is "L" not "l". To make the old project works, I removed all the localization setting and add it again. Besure all your localization resources are backed up before remove it. Hope it helps you.